# Does TFS "Track Changes" for searched local files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm not sure if you understand the question properly but here goes.

I am working on a Project checked-in to TFS. The solution has multiple projects aside from mine. I accidentally searched "Entire Solution" for something. Then when I closed Visual Studio and I got the latest version, it asks me to get the latest version from files even not from my project I was working on! I was sure I didn't check any files from there and I'm sure I didn't make any changes.

I haven't worked with TFS that much so I was not sure if that was natural behaviour. I checked all the files if something was changed but I'm pretty confident I didn't. I'm just wondering why its included in the "Get Latest File" version when I open up my Visual Studio and TFS..

Is this normal behaviour or was a change made there?

Comment: How long since you last did a get latest? Have other developers check in to other areas of the solution since then? If so then you'll be getting their changes. The search is almost certainly a red herring it won't affect source control unless you edit files or check in changes

Comment: It was a bit long since I last checked latest, but I see that the other project files its getting is still from my solution folder on my local machine? I'm not sure if thats the source though or if that is whats going to get updated.